# Redirectioning photons through magnetic lenses

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, magnetic-fields, propulsion

What shape magnet/s would I need to create parallel lines from the ends of a rod shaped magnet?or what shape of magnet would create parallel lines?[image][image]

Is this close?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_coil

Comment: I'm not seeing the connection to protons?